# How to form a graph for file folders using Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, graph, networkx

I am looking to generate a graph using Python (Pandas and Networkx) for a file folder. So far I have managed to import the data into a DataFrame, where every row corresponds to a folder link, and every column corresponds to a folder:

Example: If folder link was: C:\User\some_folder\foo\foo2\last_folder

```
  0     1         2           3     4        5     
0 C    User  some_folder     foo   foo2  last_folder
```

It would look like the above.

What is the graph algorithm that lets me connect the last element to the element before that, and that element to the element before?

Comment: but file system structures dont make graphs they make trees, what would the value of a node be if it represented a folder? the name of the folder? then what if there were 2 folders named the same? you need to consider exactly how you want your final data structure to look like **before** going in to stack overflow - and you need to describe how you want that data structure to look like when you ask a question like this

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where df,

```
   0     1            2    3     4            5
0  C  User  some_folder  foo  foo2  last_folder
```

Use, pandas to generate an edgelist of source and destination nodes:

```
df1 = df.stack()[0].to_frame(name='source')    
df1 = df1.assign(dest = df1.shift(-1)).dropna()
print(df1)
```

Output:

```
        source         dest
0            C         User
1         User  some_folder
2  some_folder          foo
3          foo         foo2
4         foo2  last_folder
```

Convert edgelist dataframe to graph using networkx with `from_pandas_edgelist`

```
import networkx as nx
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df1, 'source','dest')
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,8))
nx.draw_networkx(G, ax = ax)
```

Out:
[image]

Comment: Thank you for the help! The actual file contains about 13000 lines, so what I did was I removed the "[0]" from df1 = df.stack()[0].to_frame(name='source'), and tried to plot it that way, but I don't actually see any plots. 

Edit: It doesn't seem to matter whether I delete the "[0]" or don't. I am guessing plt is matplotlib.pyplot?

Comment: Limit it to 10 lines and try to plot to see if it is working at all.  Use `df.head().stack()`

Comment: I added plt.show() at the end and I can see the graph now! Thanks again!